# How regular expression assertions can be written in shell script in ubuntu

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu

The following is a valid regex in many languages, but it doesn't work in bash:

```
((?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[@#$%]).{6,20})
```

How can I write this regex in a shell script?

Comment: `bash` does not support lookahead or lookbehind assertions. Please give a concrete example so that a workaround can be suggested.

Comment: Password validation with atleast one digit,one symbol and one alphabet using shell scirpt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since bash does not implement lookahead assertions, you need to either use a utility which does (for example, `grep` with the `-P` option, if available on your system, or a scripting language such as Perl or Python), or break it down into different tests:

```
if [[ $pwd =~ [[:digit:]] &&
      $pwd =~ [[:upper:]] &&
      $pwd =~ [[:lower:]] &&
      $pwd =~ [@#$%] &&
      $pwd =~ ^.{6,20}$ ]]; then
    # $pwd satisfies all tests
else
    # $pwd fails some test
fi
```